# Way to use Twilio Java Message class in sdk without relying on Twilio singleton

Tags: java, twilio

[ I am looking through the source code on my own to find the answer also]

The demo code and uses a Twilio singleton

```
Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
Message message = Message.fetcher("SMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").fetch();
```

Is there a way to utilize the Message builder part of the sdk without the singleton holding the auth?

Something like

```
Message.fetcher("xxxx")
       .fetch( [twilio Auth] )
```

**EDIT**

The Message builders can take an argument in the final method call [create,fetch,read,delete].

It's an instance of TwilioRestClient. I'm ging to try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

As you've pointed out, the builders can take an instance of `TwilioRestClient` as an argument to calls like `fetch`.

I wanted to point a few things out here for understanding of the library.

`Twilio.init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN)` doesn't create a singleton instance of anything but the class `Twilio` itself. It does set the `username` and `password` static properties of the class though. The builder methods then use `Twilio.getRestClient()` to retrieve either a new or stored `TwilioRestClient` that uses those credentials.

You can build your own `TwilioRestClient` for use with the fetch calls yourself though. That would look like this:

```
TwilioRestClient.Builder builder = new TwilioRestClient.Builder(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
builder.accountSid(ACCOUNT_SID);
TwilioRestClient restClient = builder.build();
```

Then you could use that `restClient` in your `fetcher` calls:

```
Message message = Message.fetcher("SMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").fetch(restClient);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Twilio made it overcomplicated! Any user who just want to use multiple credentials has to use this workaround. The Twilio.init() is the problem. Also: builder.accountSid(ACCOUNT_SID); is not needed