# Twilio cannot handle multiple Auth accounts after upgrade from 5.x to 7.x

Tags: java, twilio, twilio-api

I upgraded a Twilio jar from twilio-java-sdk 5.9.0 to twilio 7.0.0 in a Java Spring project. There are 2 Twilio auth accounts (say A & B) for 2 different use cases in this project. 
In 5.9.0, we use a TwilioRestClient bean for each account. This allowed the 2 accounts to run in the project.
But after the upgrade to 7.x, TwilioRestClient is deprecated and we just initiate Twilio like this.

```
Twilio.init(twilioSID, twilioAuth);
```

SMS is sent for one use case with credentials A, while the other bean that uses credential B throws an error like this. Note - I have redacted the number.

```
com.twilio.exception.ApiException: The From phone number XXXXXXXXXX is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.
```

I think this is because the 2 components' call to initiate Twilio account has overlapped and we cannot isolate the 2 accounts.

Is this assumption correct? Is there a known approach/design to pattern to handle this? Does Twilio 7.x support multiple accounts?  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Apparently it's just not possible. This is bad. I can't load the Twilio library multiple times just to support multiple Twilio accounts. Mailed the support about it.

Comment: answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45427052/394646 (TwilioRestClient is not deprecated in the current version of Twilio sdk - 8.32.0)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to maintain one Twilio account for the project after the upgrade to 7.x.